# javascript toggling to show and hide specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

As written below, I have form that sends some information. 
The `Toggle` button below exists to show specific `<td>`tag and hide the others when clicked.
I marked with `here` which should be shown when toggled, and `here2` which should be hidden when toggled.

```
                    <td> <button id="to">Toggle</button> </td>
   here2 --->       <td> <img src="https: ~ "</td>
                    <td> </td>
                <% end %>
                <%= mv.hidden_field :tid, :value => movie.id %>
                <%= mv.hidden_field :nid, :value => (@matchables[movie.title] != 0 ? @matchables[movie.title].naver_id : "") %>
  here -->      <td><%= mv.text_field :nid, class: 'input-mini', placeholder: 'ID', value: (@matchables[movie.title] != 0 ? @matchables[movie.title].movie_id : "") %></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'delete', delete_item_admin_theaters_path(theater_id: movie.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag('Register' , class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

To do this I wrote simple scripts like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("button").click(function () { $("td").toggle(); });
</script>
```

However, I got some problems.

The first one is that when I click the button, it actually seems like to activate `submit_tag` as well. There by rendering weird page as well.

Second problem is that when I click the button, since `td` tag is not specified, it erases all the `td` tags.

Also I'd like to know how can set visibility of tags separately so that toggling can effectively work.

Comment: I'd like to hide here2 and show here1. So before that, here1 should be hidden and here2 should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second problem:
I would give the tds some unique ids. And then run toggle only on those ids using jquery id-selectors
You also need to make sure the "here td" is hidden when the page is loaded. You can do this by adding a css option for hiding it (like display:none), or hiding it at document load using jquery $("#theId").hide().

Now assuming the "here td's" ID is "movie_title" and the "here2 td's" ID is "image" your script should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("button").click(function () { $("#movie_title").toggle(); $("#image").toggle();  });
</script>
```

For the first problem:
Using the $("button") selector will select all your buttons which could potentially cause problems. Try suing unique ids like you already have on your button (id="to") and then use id-selectors like $("#to")

Good luck!

/Teo

Comment: The script for hiding the movie_title could be:
   `<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#movie_title").hide();
        });
    </script>`

Comment: I understood your point to manage with id, but button problem is not solved. It keeps clicking all the buttons